# ASP.NET Core Empty Application throwing error

Tags: asp.net-core

I created an empty ASP.NET Core Web Application for the first time in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. 
Upon building the project, it is throwing the error

The below command is throwing error

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design
```

> Error NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.
>   No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Offline
>   Packages  SF.CoreWebApps  D:\DellVostro15\SandFirms\SandFirms\SF.CoreWebApps\SF.CoreWebApps.csproj    1

Tried downloading the packages using packet Manager Console.

The packages are not getting downloaded and the Dependencies section is with warning symbol.

[image]

[image]

I am opening it in Admin Mode.

Comment: Have tried the instructions as given here, But couldn't get resolve,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376567/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-package-nuget-error

Comment: Your dependencies mention 2.1 which means that you are likely using an outdated .NET Core SDK. Download the latest .NET Core 2.2 SDK from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2). You should pick the `SDK 2.2.107` (look for support for VS 2017 on the left).

Comment: whoa !!! Saved my time.. Thanks a lot. After installing .NET Core 2.2 SDK and creating the project, the Build is successful.. Thanks @poke