# How to build OPC Foundation .NET library with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I am trying to build the OPC foundation provided SDK by visual studio. I face lots of builds error.
I tried VS2013, VS2017 community version, and VS2019 professional version.
Does anybody have experience building this SDK?

The source code can be downloaded from Github.
https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard

Following images show the dot net version and the errors

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume those errors contains sensitive information like directories on your drive, this is why you didn't post even single one as an example, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Which solution are you trying to build? 
As astrowalker indicated can you share the error messages?

This worked for me:

1. cloned the repository
2. opened solution "UA Core Library" within VS2019
3. restore nuget packages
4. rebuild solution
5. run all test of project "Opc.Ua.Core.Tests"

Comment: Thanks, I am using  VS2017  community version, I see huge amount of errors, have you done anything with  NuGet package manager, I tried to install missing stuff but no luck

Comment: Can you Post the error messages? (As best the first ones that appear).

Comment: I added screenshot into the original question

Comment: The Nuget package "Portable.BouncyCastle" isn't installed, try again right click on the solution "UA Core Library" and than click on "Restore Nuget packages". Before doing it, I would open the "Package Manager Console" and check i there are any errors while installing.

Comment: No luck, actually I tried these installing/reinstalling/cleaning Nuget but did not help. I see in these projects there are some yellow warning which did not disappear also. Do you know why I don't see any References folder in those projects?

Comment: You have installed .Net Core 2.1-202 which Looks like a preview Version (See [.Net Core 2.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1)). Try to install the latest version [.Net Core 2.1-805](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-2.1.805-windows-x64-installer).

Comment: Could you show the content of NuGet.Config or could you send it to mrahman252003@gmail.com

Comment: Finally, I found a solution!  It was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376567/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-package-nuget-error             The package source was offline !!  After adding these to the Nuget package all became fine.  Name: nuget.org ( or as you wish) Source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json