# ASP.NET Core MVC NET 5.0 HTTP Error 500.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I have an ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure with the ASP.NET Core 5 MVC when launching my project, using Microsoft Visual Studio to create the files.

When I create a new project under these conditions, along with using individual accounts for users, as soon as I click on IIS without modifying anything, I get build errors as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

This only occurs on my laptop and there is no difference in the way this is installed on my laptop compared to my desktop. I am a noob and don't know what other debugging methods you guys might need, but I would be very grateful if you could help me out! Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a proxy, antivirus or something like that installed on your laptop? Or are you running some "pre installed" version of windows home? (this one give me a lot of problems with vs in the past)

Comment: @Leo I only use windows defender for security, yes I have a pre-installed version of windows home, but I changed it to an education edition. Didn't reinstall the OS at all for this

Comment: I tried installing the specified Packages using the package manager console but it throws a bunch of red text saying it can't find the package

Comment: try the console with `-verbosity detailed`, let's see if got more detail about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, follow these steps and more that are listed below
[how to resolve "Unable to find package" nuget error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376567/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-package-nuget-error)
Your package source should look like this
[image]

Once you have gotten to this point, you will then need to install these packages using the packet manager console, to get to the packet manager console in visual studio, go tools > NuGet Packet Manager > Packet Manager console. Type in these commands:

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 5.0.11`
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI -Version 5.0.11`
`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 5.0.11`
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 5.0.11`
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 5.0.11`

Comment: Glad you found a solution, don't forget to mark it as accepted to help others finding this. The strange about that is the need of changing something that's supposed to be default (and working) after VS installation

Comment: I know, I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling it with all the same things I had on my desktop, I can't accept it until 2 days after.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like your visual studio is not able to connect to the nuget package source configured. You can refer the below link for the error details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1101

You can try setting up the package source in you visual studio, refer the steps in Microsoft documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio

Comment: Yeah nah this didn't work for me